# how to return function value in javascript

Tags: javascript, return-value

i have a function and i want to return the Event-id and End-Time but on console.log it returns undefined here is my code:

```
function Get_Event_Id() {

    return
    {
        EventId: 3
        EndTime: '2014-04-24T11:00:00'
    }
}

var test = GetEventId();
console.log(test);
```

Comment: You have a syntax error here. And the function names don't even match. So I guess this isn't the code you test. Can you build a minimal demonstrating example on http://jsbin.com ?

Comment: Google javascript asi

Comment: You have defined the function with name 'Get_Event_Id', but calling it as 'GetEventId'

Comment: I have changed that var test = Get_Event_Id(); but still it says undefined

Comment: check function name .  they are not matching.

Comment: There's still a syntax error. Test your code before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return an object.

```
var Get_Event_Id = function() {     
    return {
        EventId: 3,
        EndTime: '2014-04-24T11:00:00'
    }
};
var test = Get_Event_Id();
console.log(test.EventId);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8LcYr/

Comment: its not working but in 3, it give an error there

Comment: @billah77 It _is_ working, just copy it correctly ; ).

Comment: i just did and indeed its working

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your object is on a new line, that won't work, and the function names must be the same, and you're missing a comma after `3`

do this

```
function GetEventId() {

    return {
        EventId: 3,
        EndTime: '2014-04-24T11:00:00'
    }
}

var test = GetEventId();
console.log(test);
```

Next time before turning to Stack Overflow as your first and only option go to http://jsfiddle.net and paste your code in the Javascript box, then click on JSLint in the top bar and it will tell you any syntax errors you have

Comment: That's not the only problem here. Also, typo questions should be closed, not answered.

Comment: @JanDvorak I didn't realise about the typo, the reason i answered is because I've got stuck with the same issue before

Answer (score 0):

You can return an array instead:

```
function Get_Event_Id() {  
    var EventId = '3'; // Linked ICDs  
    var EndTime = '2014-04-24T11:00:00';
    return [EventId, EndTime];  
};

var test = Get_Event_Id();
console.log(test); // ["3", "2014-04-24T11:00:00"]
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8DYQq/)**

Comment: danx alot it did return what i want

Comment: I like your quote on your profile, but, are you serious here?